# ignoring jquery plugin datatables empty rows on post action to database with laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I have a laravel 5 app with jQuery datatables with 3 inputs in each table row. When I post them to be inserted the database I want to check that in each row at least 2 of the inputs are filled in before inserting. If at least two rows are not filled in I want to skip that row and move to the next one until it reaches the end of the table.

what i have in my controller is this:

```
$total_date    = array_diff($request->get('month'), array(''));
$total_comment = array_diff($request->get('comment'), array(''));
$total_value   = array_diff($request->get('value'), array(''));

for($i = 0; $i < count($total_date); $i++)
{
    if(array_diff($request->get('month'), array('')))
    {
        $dateString = $total_date[$i];
        $date       = explode('-', $dateString);
        $year       = $date[0];
        $month      = $date[1];

        $reports[] = Reports::create([
            'month'   => $month,
            'year'    => $year,
            'value'   => $total_value[$i],
            'comment' => $total_comment[$i]
        ]);
    }
}

return $reports;
```

This works fine if the empty rows are at the bottom of the table, but fails if I leave an empty row between 2 filled rows. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've over-complicated things. Using a combination of filtering the array and then an incremental for through the array will not work. If any entries are filtered out, your for loop won't make it to the end of your array.

Just step back and simplify it:

```
// assumes the request variables are arrays
$months = $request->get('month');
$comments = $request->get('comment');
$values = $request->get('value');

// initialize return array
$reports = [];

// assumes arrays have same number of entries
foreach($months as $key => $month) {
    $comment = $comments[$key];
    $value = $value[$key];

    // determine number of filled inputs
    $numFilled = !empty($month) + !empty($comment) + !empty($value);

    // if at least two inputs filled
    if ($numFilled >= 2) {
        $date = explode('-', $month);
        $year = isset($date[0]) ? $date[0] : '';
        $month = isset($date[1]) ? $date[1] : '';
        $reports[] = Reports::create([
            'month' => $month,
            'year' => $year,
            'value' => $value,
            'comment' => $comment
        ]);
    }
}

return $reports;
```

Also, as a complete side note, the `array_filter()` function should be used to filter arrays, not that `array_diff()` trick.

Comment: just a little edit up there.. the code seemed to perform the opposite of what it was meant to :) sometimes a exclamation mark is a life saver :)

Comment: @xhulio Ah, sorry about that. Silly mistake on my part.